# area(data) works but area does not d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create an area graph in d3.js. I wrote the following function:

```
  @drawAreaChart = (element,chart_value)->
console.log("Im in")
height=400              
data=chart_value
chart_area=d3.select(element)
area = d3.svg.area().x( (d) -> 
  return d.x 
)
.y0(height)
.y1( (d) ->          
  return height-d.y
).interpolate("linear")
line = d3.svg.line().x( (d) -> 
  return d.x
)
.y( (d) ->          
  return height-d.y
).interpolate("linear")
chart_area.selectAll(".line").data(data).enter().append("path").attr("d",line(data)).attr("class","line").attr("fill","none").attr("stroke","rgb(100,153,255)").attr("stroke-width",2)    
chart_area.selectAll(".area").data(data).enter().append("path").attr("d",area(data)).attr("class",".area").attr("fill","url(#gradient-effect)")    
return
```

The chart_value is being passed the following data:

```
      charts.drawAreaChart("#area-graph",[{"x":0,"y":100},
                                      {"x":100, "y":200},
                                      {"x":200,"y":250},
                                      {"x":300, "y":300},
                                      {"x":400, "y":230},
                                      {"x":500, "y":260},
                                      {"x":600, "y":160}]);
```

The function is within a charts module hence charts.drawAreaChart is being called. Now the problem is, the above code works for static data. I haven't tested for dynamic data. However if I use

```
chart_Area.selectAll(".area").data(data).enter().append("path").attr("d",area)
```

instead of

```
chart_Area.selectAll(".area").data(data).enter().append("path").attr("d",area(data))
```

the chart does not appear. The same happens with my line graph but in another function I create an arc and there i do not need to write it as attr("d",arc(data))

Answer (score 1):

D3's `.data()` function expects an array of items, each of which represents one of the DOM elements that you've been selecting (in your case `.area`). You're passing in an array of points, which means that D3 matches each *point* to a new DOM element. So the `area` function is being passed a single point.

When you call `area(data)` explicitly in this context, you're actually get several areas -- one per point.

To make this work without giving the argument explicitly, pass in the area data as an array, i.e.

```
chart_Area.selectAll(".area").data([data]).enter().append("path").attr("d",area);
```